# Values in one column based on condition in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
Data = {'group':  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'],
        'value1': [2, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 6, 31, 7, 5, 0, 99],
        'value2': [25, 12 ,15, 11, 36, 3, 65, 6, 89, 8, 74, 5]
        }

current_result = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns = ['group','value1', 'value2'])
```

I want to set `value2` to zero if corresponding `value1` is equal to zero while keeping all other values the same. So my desired result would be:

```
Data = {'group':  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'],
        'value1': [2, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 6, 31, 7, 5, 0, 99],
        'value2': [25, 0 ,0, 11, 36, 3, 65, 6, 89, 8, 0, 5]
        }

current_result = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns = ['group','value1', 'value2'])
```

How could I do this?

Comment: ```df.loc[df['value1'] == 0, 'value2'] = 0```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`df.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
current_result.loc[current_result.value1.eq(0),'value2']=current_result.value1
print(current_result)
```

---

```
   group  value1  value2
0      a       2      25
1      b       0       0
2      c       0       0
3      d       5      11
4      e       5      36
5      f       5       3
6      g       6      65
7      h      31       6
8      i       7      89
9      j       5       8
10     k       0       0
11     l      99       5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can multiple by boolean mask - `True` are processes like `1`,`False` like `0` so compare for not equal `0` by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html):

```
current_result['value2'] *= current_result['value1'].ne(0)
print (current_result)
   group  value1  value2
0      a       2      25
1      b       0       0
2      c       0       0
3      d       5      11
4      e       5      36
5      f       5       3
6      g       6      65
7      h      31       6
8      i       7      89
9      j       5       8
10     k       0       0
11     l      99       5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  this:

```
current_result.loc[current_result['value1'] == 0, ['value2']] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
current_result.loc[current_result['value1'] == 0, 'value2'] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any Pandas core features, this loop gets the job done:

```
for index, value in enumerate(current_result["value1"]):
    if value == 0:
        current_result["value2"][index] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def change_value(row):
    if row.value1 == 0:
        row.value2 = 0
    return row


current_result = current_result.apply(change_value, axis=1)
```

Comment: Could you write a quick note about why this works to help future people who come across the question and want to know more?